# Save video encoded by libavcodec to an AVI file format

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, avi

I am able to encode video frames using libavcodec, by calling `avcodec_encode_video` function. How do I save these encoded frames into an AVI file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-112286.html

You must open file for binary write, write header in it, and simultaniosly put binary frames in it, I think.

Comment: I tried that, but this seems to work only on few codec like MPEG or H264 but does not work for FLV1 or Huffyuv for instance...